# Find the maximum value of expression $13\sqrt{(x^2-x^4)}+9\sqrt{(x^2+x^4)}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, radicals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Find the maximum value of expression $$13\sqrt{(x^2-x^4)}+9\sqrt{(x^2+x^4)}$$ for $0\le x \le 1$

My Attempt
$(x^2)(1 - x^2) \le \frac{x^2+(1 - x^2)}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow 13\sqrt{(x^2-x^4)} \le \frac{13}{\sqrt 2}$
Same way we obtain $9\sqrt{(x^2+x^4)} \le \frac{9}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1+2x^2} $
As $0\le x \le 1$ so $\sqrt{1+2x^2} \le \sqrt{3}$ .
Hence, maximum is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(13+9\sqrt{3})$ occurs at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
I then checked the value in wolfram alfa and found that maximum is $16$ and occurs at $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$.
Can anyone point my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=13\sqrt{x^2-x^4}+9\sqrt{x^2+x^4},\;x\in[0,1]$

$$f'(x)=\frac{9 \left(4 x^3+2 x\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^4+x^2}}+\frac{13 \left(2 x-4 x^3\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2-x^4}}=0$$
as $x>0$ we can simplify
$$\frac{18 x \left(2 x^2+1\right)}{2 x \sqrt{x^2+1}}+\frac{26 x \left(1-2 x^2\right)}{2 x \sqrt{1-x^2}}=0 \to \frac{9 \left(2 x^2+1\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{13 \left(2 x^2-1\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Substitute $x^2= u-1$ as $0\le x^2\le 1$ then $1\le u\le 2$
$$\frac{9 (2 (u-1)+1)}{\sqrt{u}}=\frac{13 (2 (u-1)-1)}{\sqrt{2-u}}$$
square both sides, reorder and simplify

$500 u^3-1500 u^2+1125 u-81=0$

Factor $(5 u-9) \left(100 u^2-120 u+9\right)=0$

gives $u_1=\frac{9}{5},u_2=\frac{3}{10} \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right),u_3=\frac{3}{10} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)$

$u_2$ is out of the interval $(1,2)$

so we have $x^2=u_1-1=\dfrac{4}{5} \to x_1=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt 5}$  and

$x^2=u_3-1 \to x_2=\dfrac{1}{10} \sqrt{30 \sqrt{3}-40}$

$f(x_1)=16;\;f(x_3)=\dfrac{1}{10} \sqrt{7974 \sqrt{3}-8168}\approx 7.51$

Maximum value of $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$ is $f\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt 5}\right)=16$

hope it is useful

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing all the steps. It is now clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$ we get a value $16$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

We need to prove that
$$13x\sqrt{1-x^2}+9x\sqrt{1+x^2}\leq16$$ or
$$44x^4-125x^2+128\geq117x^2\sqrt{1-x^4}$$ or
$$(5x^2-4)^2(625x^4+560x^2+1024)\geq0.$$

Also, we can use C-S and AM-GM:

Let $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}t$.

Thus,
$$13x\sqrt{1-x^2}+9x\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac{2}{5}t\left(13\sqrt{5-4t^2}+9\sqrt{5+4t^2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{2}{5}t\left(13\sqrt{5-4t^2}+27\sqrt{\frac{5}{9}+\frac{4}{9}t^2}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{2}{5}t\sqrt{(13+27)\left(13(5-4t^2)+27\left(\frac{5}{9}+\frac{4}{9}t^2\right)\right)}=$$
$$=16t\sqrt{2-t^2}\leq16\cdot\frac{t^2+2-t^2}{2}=16.$$

Comment: Where's the proof?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel He'll edit the post in a few seconds and include it

Comment: @Benjamin Moss I am sorry! I found a mistake in my proof, but I fixed it. Now, this is a proof.

Comment: You're good, I was merely remarking that you were getting your foot in the door by writing the first few lines to indicate you were formulating your proof, and then you were going to post it, which I am okay with.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I am bit confused. It is a contest problem. The knowledge that maximum is 16 and occur at $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt(5)}$ is not possible to guess in exam structure. I believe there must be a proof which will directly arrive at these numbers. Any way thanks for your proof.

Comment: @rugi But you can see that I proved it! See my second proof. The value $\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$ we can get, when we think about an equality occurring in AM-GM and in C-S. I really don't understand you!